# I need a exp:stash:get closing table?

Tags: stash

I I use this syntax, stash work well

```
{exp:stash:get name="contenuto"}

{/exp:stash:get}
```

if I omit `{/exp:stash:get}`, I receive an error from expression engine.

I didn't found examples with name= and the closing tag.

I'm right in my syntax?

Comment: Using it without the closing tag is perfectly valid, in fact I can't think of any reason you would want the tag pair in there, just the single tag is all you need.

To understand your problem more we would need the error your getting, and maybe your entire template, or at least a stripped down version showing all the important tags. You can

Comment: What version of Stash and EE are you using? I can confirm it works for me with Stash 2.3.6 (beta) and 2.1.0. Both with EE 2.5.5

Comment: Does this work for you: `{exp:stash:contenuto}`?

Comment: `{exp:stash:get_list}` is the tag pair equivalent (kinda). But like others have said, we'll need to know what you're trying to do before we can help.